# Python Tensorflow - how does GradientTape operate and why can it give None as a result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, gradienttape

**Abstract**
I am trying to create a neural network with custom training. In my attempts I ended up with a
`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable` error. While trying to figure it out, I've found out that the problem appears because GradientTape sees no connection between the parameters given in `GradientTape.gradient()` which in turn usually happens because not every variable is watched by default and some of them weren't marked with a `watch()` function.

**Problem**
The code here raises the value error `` ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is (None,... ``  because `GradientTape.gradient()` returns a list of `None` instead of gradients for some reason.
The code (this is only a draft so it is kind of dirty):

```
def der2(f, x):
    res = [(f[0] - 2 * f[1] + f[2]) / ((x[1] - x[0]) * (x[2] - x[1]))] * 2
    res.extend(
        [(f[i - 1] - 2 * f[i] + f[i + 1]) / ((x[i] - x[i - 1]) * (x[i + 1] - x[i])) for i in range(2, len(f) - 2)])
    res.extend([(f[-3] - 2 * f[-2] + f[-1]) / ((x[-1] - x[-2]) * (x[-2] - x[-3]))] * 2)
    return res


dim1 = 50
dim2 = 50


def loss(model, x, y, training):
    y_ = model(x)

    s = 0
    for inputs, result in zip(x, y_):
        res_matrix = result.numpy()
        res_matrix = np.reshape(res_matrix, (dim1, dim2))
        transposed = res_matrix.transpose()
        si = list()
        sj = list()
        for yi in res_matrix:
            si.append(der2(yi, inputs[:dim1]))
        for yi in transposed:
            sj.append(der2(yi, inputs[dim1:]))
        si = np.array(si) + np.transpose(np.array(sj))
        si = tf.reduce_sum(si)
        for i in range(len(res_matrix)):
            for j in range(len(transposed)):
                si += 30 * np.exp(0.007 * ((inputs[i] - 5) ** 2) * ((inputs[dim1 + j] - 5) ** 2))
        s += abs(si)

    return s / 2500


def grad(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=True)
    return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)


num_epochs = 1501

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=dim1)
x = np.append(x, np.linspace(0, 10, num=dim2))
y = 0
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([[x]], [[y]]))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_shape=(100,), activation=tf.nn.relu),  # input shape required
    Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(2500, dtype='float64')
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.00001)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    # Training loop - using batches of 32
    for x, y in train_dataset:
        # Optimize the model
        loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        epoch_loss_avg.update_state(loss_value)

    if epoch % 50 == 0:
        avg_loss = epoch_loss_avg.result()
        optimizer.learning_rate = avg_loss / 1000
        print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}".format(epoch, avg_loss))

for x, y in train_dataset:
    y_ = model(x)
    plt.plot(x[0], y_[0])
plt.show()
```

**My understanding of what happens**

I have three code samples.

1. The one that works fine:

```
def der(f, x):
    res = [(f[1] - f[0]) / (x[1] - x[0])] * 2
    res.extend([(f[i] - f[i - 1]) / (x[i] - x[i - 1]) for i in range(2, len(f))])
    return res


def loss(model, x, y, tape, training):
    y_ = model(x)

    s = 0
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y_):
        lq = (1 + 3 * (xi ** 2)) / (1 + xi + xi ** 3)
        s += tf.reduce_sum(abs((der(yi, xi) + (xi + lq) * yi - xi ** 3 - 2 * xi - lq * xi * xi)))

    return s / tf.size(x).numpy()
```

Since it works fine I thought the problem is probuably because GradientTape only watches the output layer (`yi` in this sample) but not the `result_matrix` and `transposed` from the main problem code. So i've tried to simulate the same operations in sample #1 by adding `yi = yi.numpy()` and `yi = tf.convert_to_tensor(yi)` and making it a new variable and got code sample #2:

2. This code results in the same error as the main problem code:

```
def loss(model, x, y, tape, training)
    y_ = model(x)

    s = 0
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y_):
        yi = yi.numpy()
        yi = tf.convert_to_tensor(yi)
        lq = (1 + 3 * (xi ** 2)) / (1 + xi + xi ** 3)
        s += tf.reduce_sum(abs((der(yi, xi) + (xi + lq) * yi - xi ** 3 - 2 * xi - lq * xi * xi)))

    return s / tf.size(x).numpy()
```

So i thought that simply adding `tape.watch(yi)` would solve it, but it did not:

3. This code sample also results in the same error.

```
def loss(model, x, y, tape, training)
    y_ = model(x)

    s = 0
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y_):
        yi = yi.numpy()
        yi = tf.convert_to_tensor(yi)
        tape.watch(yi)
        lq = (1 + 3 * (xi ** 2)) / (1 + xi + xi ** 3)
        s += tf.reduce_sum(abs((der(yi, xi) + (xi + lq) * yi - xi ** 3 - 2 * xi - lq * xi * xi)))

    return s / tf.size(x).numpy()
```

Since that did not fix the problem, i clearly misunderstand something about how GradientTape operates.

Comment: Part of the issue could be that you use numpy operations in your loss function. Gradients will not flow through numpy arrays. Only use tensorflow operations.

Comment: @jkr Well you were right, thank you. I've replaced every numpy operation with an equivalent  tensorflow operation and now it does not raise the value. However, i still dont understand why would code sample #3 raise it if I made `yi` back to a tensor and explicitly used a watch() on it

Comment: why do you need `tape.watch(yi)`?

Comment: regarding code sample 3, `yi.numpy()` will break the flow of gradients, even though it is converted back to a tensor in the next line.

Comment: [Info], you can try tensorflow numpy api (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy).